# Normalized measure from dynamic time warping

Tags: machine-learning, pattern-recognition, time-series-analysis

I am trying to find the similarity between two time series, but not in terms of distance, in something more sensible such as percentage of similarity. In other words I need something that shows the similarity, not dis-similarity.

The dynamic time warping gives a very good response, when trying to compare the time-series. But the distance computed by dynamic time warping depends on the duration of the time series and the magnitude of the template and the query. Moreover, it shows the distance, which demonstrates the dis-similarity.

Is there a way to convert the distance from DTW into some form of normalized similarity measure?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sure.  There's a straightforward way to convert an unnormalized distance metric into a normalized similarity measure.  Basically, use

$$S(x,y) = \frac{M - D(x,y)}{M},$$

where $D(x,y)$ is the distance between $x$ and $y$, $S$ is the normalized similarity measure between $x$ and $y$, and $M$ is the maximum value that $D(x,y)$ could be.

In the case of dynamic time warping, given a template $x$, one can compute the maximum possible value of $D(x,y)$.  This will depend on the template, so $M$ becomes $M(x)$, and the formula becomes

$$S(x,y) = \frac{M(x) - D(x,y)}{M(x)}.$$

So how do you compute $M(x)$?  Basically, multiply the length of the template (the number of samples in the time series), times the maximum value of each sample.  If each sample is in the range $[0,1]$, then the maximum value of each sample is 1, so $M(x)$ becomes just the length of $x$.  This gives a simple upper bound on $D(x,y)$.  [Trivia: in fact one could compute a slightly tighter upper bound, but in practice that's probably not necessary.]

It is easy to verify that the similarity measure is always in the range $[0,1]$ and thus is normalized as you were hoping for.

Comment: Thank you very much. The measure of similarity is very intuitive and nice. I have a couple of questions:
1- Why this multiplication (length (templaye)*max(template)) results in the farest distant? 
2- We are talking about absolute maximum, right?

Comment: I think we should some hoe take the magnitude of the signal being checked against the sample into account. Let's assume the following condition:
a=[1,2,3,4,5]
Then the time-series that result in highest distance will be:
b=[25,25,25,25,25]% from max(a)*length(a)
The result DTW distance is: 49.29
But if we now just increase b by 1: b2=[26,26,26,26,26], we reach to even higher distance = 51.52. 
Am I missing some thing here?

Comment: @AminGhaderi, it's easiest to think about it in the case where each sample in the time series is required to be in the range $[0,1]$.  In practice usually each sample must come from some bounded range -- the samples can't be arbitrarily large -- so they can be normalized to the range $[0,1]$.

Comment: This is great. Thank you for the very nice responses. 
How about if the magnitude (range) of the time series is also an informative feature for this specific application. In other words, we might have two time distinctive time series that have same shape (i.e.  negligible distance if normalized to [0,1]), but since their magnitude is different, they have different they are not the same.

Comment: The issue with this method is that the answer is compressed near to 1. We found values like 0.99999 or 0.99998 but never values like 0.1 or 0.2. because the longest path is never taken and the maximal difference between the two signals happens only once.

Comment: @ymmx how do you fix this problem? I compute m=max(a)*length(a) but as you said I get only value arround 0.9999. Thanks

Comment: I don't see why it is a problem that the answer is compressed near 1.  Presumably all you are going to do with this metric is compare two solutions to see which has a higher value of the metric, so I don't see what goes wrong.  To put it another way: it seems to satisfy all of the requirements in the question.  So, if it's not satisfactory, I'm guessing that means you have some additional requirement not present in this question.  If so, I suggest you think about what that requirement is, then ask a new question with the 'Ask Question' button.

Comment: Hi @D.W.thanks for your reply. I think I'm missing something in implementing the solution. Considering the following two series; y = [100,100,100,100,100] z = [0,0,0,0,0], I get dtw_dist = 223.61, I expect that this value corresponds to 0% similarity, while I get 55%. I'm sure there something wrong in my interpretation and implementation. In my code M = len(y)*max(y) = 5 * 100 = 500! 
Where is my error?

Comment: @Deborah, how did you get the maximum value $M$?  I doubt those two sequences are maximally dissimilar; y'=[500,500,500,500,500] would be even more dissimilar from z, so needs to have even lower similarity.

Comment: @D.W. simply for me M = len(y)*max(y), where len(y) is the number of samples in y and max(y) is the max value among samples in y. I'm sure I'm missing something!

Comment: @Deborah, there's the flaw.  That's not a correct way to compute the maximum.

Comment: @D.W. exactly ... would you tell me how to calculate it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123621/discussion-between-deborah-and-d-w).

Comment: Do you compute the maximum possible distance between two time series of unequal lengths? This seems to only apply to the case where they are the same length...

Comment: @rocksNwaves, correct, if they are unequal length you will need to adjust how the maximum value is computed.  Probably it becomes the length of whichever one is longer, but I haven't thought about it carefully and I will let you work out the details.

Comment: I just tried your method on two identical test sequences and two vastly different sequences, both sets of the same length. Respectively their scores were 0.9998 and 0.9996. It does not normalize to the range [0, 1]. It normalizes within some range like (.999, 0.9998). It was a nice stab at normalization but truly doesn't work. I think you should edit your answer unless you've tried it yourself and have some proof that it works as advertised.

Comment: @rocksNwaves, OK.  It's hard for me to diagnose without seeing an example or knowing how you generated the two vastly different sequences.  Perhaps my suggestion for $M$ was a poor upper bound, I don't know.  Or, perhaps it is possible to create a pair of different test sequences that would yield an even lower value.  It is hard for me to understand why you didn't get exactly 1 when using two identical sequences.  I don't have experience with this, so my answer might well be flawed.  I'm not sure what to say.  Thank you for sharing your experience.

Comment: `x= np.random.randn(10)` `y = x`. Perform DTW and normalize the output score with `M = len(x) * max(x)`

Comment: @rocksNwaves, my answer explicitly states "If each sample is in the range [0,1], then...."  Your Python code violates that assumption, and as such you won't be able to use the method I describe for computing $M(x)$ directly; you'll need to make some adjustments.  The natural adjustment would be the difference between the maximum possible value minus the minimum possible value (not the max of x, but the maximum possible value), times the length.  However a standard normal won't fit in any finite range.  Also, your code gives you a pair of sequences that are not maximally different.