# Comparing Directed Unweighted Graphs with Different "Densities"

Tags: algorithms, graphs, machine-learning

I'm looking to compare 2 unweighted directed graphs and get an (ideally differentiable) similarity score. Both graphs describe a trajectory in a 2d space.

The *reference graph* is a step by step guide to an end location. The nodes have a value which corresponds to a precise action such as forward 1m, left 30 degrees. The edges are only used to link steps together.

The *comparison graph* nodes on the other hand only contain directions rather than precision instructions (e.g. left, right, forward). Similarly the edges have no information.

While both graphs contain similar information,the *comparison graph* contains far fewer points (2-10x). I first tried reducing the *reference graph* to the same direction level by compressing multiple nodes of the same value together. This works somewhat, but leaves a lot to be desired. It is still too "low-level" to be directly comparable.

I'm in the process of evaluating edit distance (specifically a [soft variant](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.12562#:%7E:text=Soft%20edit%20distance%20for%20differentiable%20comparison%20of%20symbolic%20sequences,-Evgenii%20Ofitserov%2C%20Vasily&text=Edit%20distance%2C%20also%20known%20as,sequences%20and%20natural%20language%20processing.)) and [nDTW](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/53250/normalized-measure-from-dynamic-time-warping#:%7E:text=The%20dynamic%20time%20warping%20gives,which%20demonstrates%20the%20dis%2Dsimilarity.) as possible candidates.

My questions are:

1. What other metrics exist to compare graphs of this nature? I've looked at some [slides](http://www.cs.uoi.gr/%7Epvassil/downloads/GraphDistance/LauraZager.pdf) and a [survey on graph comparison](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-019-53708-y.pdf) and while these were helpful, I don't have enough intuition to choose between the methods they propose.
2. Are there other ways of comparing these 2 sequences, besides treating them as graphs?
3. Is there a community that might have a similar need? Like bio-informatics?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/487815/2921, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/130245/755, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3831049/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was cross-posted.